# Install LoadRunner on Linux?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, loadrunner

Can I install LoadRunner on Linux? and how to Integrate LoadRunner with jenkins? and what the relation between ALM(Application Lifecycle Management), UFT, and LoadRunner on jenkins?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

LoadRunner is a set of tools the main ones being VuGen, Controller, and Load Generator (LG).
The LG can be installed on Linux while VuGen and Controller cannot.

Regarding Jenkins. There is an official Jenkins plugin that helps you integrate LoadRunner and the other tools you mentioned with your CI flow. The plugin is fully maintained and is available here: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/HPE+Application+Automation+Tools

Answer (score 0):

HP Loadrunner can only be installed in windows machines.And you can execute runs only in windows. One exception is Load generator(one of the LR components) which can be installed in Linux as well for generating the Load.